# center align adsense on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, adsense

I have a Google AdSense element on my WordPress but as default it is left aligned. How can I make it center align on the horisontal axis?

The code I have tried is:

```
<div style="margin:auto">  
    //AdSende Script
</div>
```

Comment: I am using the text wifget in wordpress. As I know it takes text, html and java script

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add adsense code under center tag..or in table

```
<center>Adsense code here</center>
```

or
add table

```
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">Adsense code here</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

What if you try something like the following:

```
<div class="textwidget">
  <div class="adsense">  
    //AdSense Script
 </div> <!-- .adsense !-->
</div> <!-- .textwidget !-->
```

And in your CSS:

```
.textwidget {text-align: center;}
.adsense {margin:0 auto;}
```

Comment: Can it be done without adding information to the CSS? Maybe just adding the information to the java script?

Comment: Yes, that is possible as well.  If you are using jQuery, you can check out the .css() documentation at http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Internet Explorer make sure your DOCTYPE is set correctly or it'll enter quirksmode and break `margin:auto` functionality.

Answer (score 0):

try this simple code :

```
 <div style="float:none;margin:0px 0 0px 0;text-align:center;">
        ****your code here ****
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me. Tested!
Margin auto is fine but it needs a width to work. So:

```
<div style="max-width:400px;margin:auto">adsense code here</div>
```

**Note:** adjust width as necessary.

I successfully center adsense ads like this.